# Convert a bunch of files from guessed encoding to UTF-8

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

I have [this Python script](https://gist.github.com/asbjornu/a73c8ab7a2f733375d06) that attempts to detect the character encoding of a text file (in this case, C# `.cs` source files, but they could be any text file) and then convert them from that character encoding and into `UTF-8` (without BOM).

While [chardet](https://chardet.github.io/) detects the encoding well enough and the script runs without errors, characters like `©` are encoded into `$`. So I assume there's something wrong with the script and my understanding of encoding in Python 2. Since converting files from `UTF-8-SIG` to `UTF-8` works, I have a feeling that the problem is the decoding (reading) part and not the encoding (writing) part.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? If switching to Python 3 is a solution, I'm all for it, I then just need help figuring out how to convert the script from running on version 2.7 to 3.4. Here's the script:

```
import os
import glob
import fnmatch
import codecs
from chardet.universaldetector import UniversalDetector

# from http://farmdev.com/talks/unicode/
def to_unicode_or_bust(obj, encoding='utf-8'):
    if isinstance(obj, basestring):
        if not isinstance(obj, unicode):
            obj = unicode(obj, encoding)
    return obj

def enforce_unicode():
    detector = UniversalDetector()

    for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('.'):
      for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, '*.cs'):
        detector.reset()
        filepath = os.path.join(root, filename)

        with open(filepath, 'r') as f:
            for line in f:
                detector.feed(line)
                if detector.done: break

        detector.close()
        encoding = detector.result['encoding']

        if encoding and not encoding == 'UTF-8':
            print '%s -> UTF-8   %s' % (encoding.ljust(12), filepath)
            with codecs.open(filepath, 'r', encoding=encoding) as f:
                content = ''.join(f.readlines())

            content = to_unicode_or_bust(content)

            with codecs.open(filepath, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
                f.write(content)

enforce_unicode()
```

I have tried to do `content = content.decode(encoding).encode('utf-8')` before writing the file, but that fails with the following error:

```
/usr/local/.../lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8_sig.py:19: UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal
  if input[:3] == codecs.BOM_UTF8:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./enforce-unicode.py", line 48, in <module>
    enforce_unicode()
  File "./enforce-unicode.py", line 43, in enforce_unicode
    content = content.decode(encoding).encode('utf-8')
  File "/usr/local/.../lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8_sig.py", line 22, in decode
    (output, consumed) = codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa9' in position 87: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`chardet` simply got the detected codec it wrong, your code is otherwise correct. Character detection is based on *statistics, heuristics and plain guesses*, it is not a foolproof method.

For example, the [Windows 1252 codepage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) is **very close** to the Latin-1 codec; files encoded with the one encoding can be decoded without error in the other encoding. Detecting the difference between a control code in the one or a Euro symbol in the other usually takes a human being looking at the result.

I'd record the `chardet` guesses for each file, if the file turns out to be wrongly re-coded, you need to look at what other codecs could be close. All of the 1250-series codepages look a lot alike.

Comment: I see. But even in cases where I know the original file is in CP1252 and it is rightly detected, the conversion fails. The © symbol is converted into garbage.

Comment: @asbjornu how are you displaying the file? What tool is used to open it? Other code you produced is not garbling anything. Can you give us sample bytes that illustrate the problem? I put, detected codec and what bytes end up being written.

Comment: I ended up solving this with C# instead, but I'll accept your answer since you're most probably right. Thanks!